# htaccess RewriteRule redirecting unexpectedly www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my htaccess I have a rule -

I have this rule

```
RewriteRule ^mk$ http://mysite.com/mypage.php [r=301,nc]
```

and later on :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

This works fine for 
`http://mysite.com/mk`
- it redirects to:
`http://mysite.com/mypage.php` 
as I wanted.

...but when I go to 
`http://www.mysite.com/mk`
it redirects to http://mysite.com/http://mysite.com/mypage.php

Are these 2 rules incompatable? Can anyone tell me what's happening and what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are compatible, but in your case I think order matters. I would move the *host* redirect above the *mk* redirect and try again.

Another thing would be to add the `L` flag (Last) to the *mk* rule. This should trigger the redirect immediately.

I am not sure if you have any other rules that you want to run first. So see what the order does if that matters to you. Essentially these rules are pairing up and *double* rewriting `http://www.mysite.com/mk`